alsamixer reset when console switched
In Ubuntu 24 LTS, using Xubuntu, but Gnome is also installed, alsamixer settings are reset to some default every time I switch consoles.
When I press Ctrl + Alt + F3 to switch the terminal and when I click Switch User, alsamixer is reset to some default which is beyond my control. There is no need to logout or login into any account for this to happen. Just leaving the current user account is enough.
I searched the net but it's all about how to set alsamixer settings at boot. I am doing that in ~/.bashrc. I have no idea where to look to solve this problem. /var/lib/alsa/asound.state is ignored when this happens, I don't know where is saved that default state. It didn't happen in Ubuntu 22 LTS.
